# How can I terminate a string with regex_replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using CreateProcess to run a bash script via Cygwin's bash.exe and redirecting the output (because that's what the customer wants). The only problem still left to solve is that if ReadFile doesn't fill up lpBuffer I end up with a bunch of junk characters at the end of it, which I would like to filter out. Usually, this is something like:

```
"ÌÌÌÌ...ÌÌÌÌÌuÆì¨õD"
```

for which the code below will give me:

```
"uÆì¨õD"
```

So, I'm at least partially successful =D

However, what I'd really like is to just terminate the string at the first junk character, preferably with a newline also, but I can't seem to find a variation of fmt that works.

```
void ReadAndHandleOutput(HANDLE hPipeRead) {
char lpBuffer[256];
DWORD nBytesRead;
wstringstream wss;
while(TRUE)
{
    if(!ReadFile(hPipeRead, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), &nBytesRead, NULL) || !nBytesRead)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Filter out the weird non-ascii characters.
    std::string buffer(lpBuffer); 
    std::regex rx("[^[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]+"); 
    std::string fmt("\n\0");
    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type fonly = std::regex_constants::format_first_only;
    std::string result = std::regex_replace(buffer, rx, fmt, fonly);
    wss << result.c_str();
}
SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(HwndMain, IDC_OUTPUT), LPCWSTR(wss.str().c_str())); }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function returns the number of bytes read? You can null out the rest of the buffer.

Comment: It does, and that did turn out to be the correct solution, with one modification: my buffer needed to be one element bigger than the max size value passed to ReadFile so I could ensure that it's always null terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure fixing it with regex is all right. I believe you should put a `\0` in where the input has finished, and you can find out the location by retrieving the number of characters read.

However, these are the set of *printable* (non-junk) ASCII characters:

```
[ -~]
```

Which is the set of characters from space to tilde.

So this is the desired pattern:

```
[^ -~]+
```

Comment: Correct on both counts. This pattern is much closer to what I was looking for, but the correct solution was to make use of nBytesRead.